# How to move a programmed game for pc to android

Tags: java, android

I've developed a game on my computer in java, but realized it's not really a game I want to play on my computer but something I want on my phone (a samsung galaxy S3). Is there an easy way to make it an android application?

Comment: It might be helpful (even essential) to provide more detailed informationen on what kind of frameworks/technologies (e.g. OpenGL, Canvas...) you used for the game.

Comment: I would look into Cocos2d-x (C++) http://www.cocos2d-x.org/ or Cocos2d Android https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/

Answer (score 2):

There are two cross platform projects I recommend for this purpose. [LIBGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), and [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/).

You will be able to reuse some of your code, but will need to change any code using objects which do not exist for the android platform (java.awt.Point, java.awt.Rectangle, Graphics, Graphics2D, etc.)

I have used LIBGDX personally, and give it the highest recommendation. PlayN I have not, but have heard good things.